# How do I set the max height for window view in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my first time working with react and we inherited code from another programmer who previously worked on the project.  We have a new screen that has objects too big to fit within it and thus creates an unwanted scrollbar for the whole screen.  This creates a weird glitch effect when we have any kind of animation going on and it's because the object on the page overflows of the bottom of the screen.

Do I need to call the update dimensions function on the screen in question or should I just update our default export to match 100% view height?  I don't know how to do either, so if one method is preferred please explain how to do it.  Thank you

import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

```
let width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
let height = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);

window.onresize = updateDimensions;

export function updateDimensions() {
  location.reload();
  width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
  height = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
};

export default {
  window: {
    width,
    height,
  },
  mobile: width < 400,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need `useState` and `useEffect` to do that. Here is what I'd solve the problem:

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ window, screen });

useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener(
      "change",
      ({ window, screen }) => {
        setDimensions({ window, screen });
      }
    );
    return () => subscription?.remove();
});
```